# jquery conditional operator for attr function

Tags: jquery, ternary-operator

```
$("<button>")
    .addClass("radio")
    .addClass(this._getValue(lbl) ? "checked" : "")
    .attr(this._getDisableProp(lbl) ? ("disabled", "disabled") : "")
    .prop(this._getDisableProp(lbl) ? ("disabled", true) : ("disabled", false));
```

in the above code, i am trying to add `attr` and `prop` only when my function returns true. i did that similarly for `addClass` and it worked, but it is not working for `attr` and `prop`.

is there any work arounds please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot chose multiple function arguments based on the ternary operator. You can only select one. So do something like:

```
$("button")
         .addClass("radio")
         .addClass(this._getValue(lbl) ? "checked" : "")
         .attr("disabled" , this._getDisableProp(lbl) ? "disabled" : "")
         .prop("disabled", this._getDisableProp(lbl) ? true : false);
```

However I would recommend only using the property as "disabled" attribute set to "" will still disable the element (which would get overridden by property anyway):

```
$("button")
         .addClass("radio")
         .addClass(this._getValue(lbl) ? "checked" : "")
         .prop("disabled", this._getDisableProp(lbl) ? true : false);
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ (Attributes vs. Properties).. read that says why i used both attr and prop

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
.prop("disabled", this._getDisableProp(lbl))
```

You don't want the ternary operator on the whole thing... just the value (which will be different depending on the condition)

Do note that even a blank value for the disabled attribute will cause the element to be disabled, that's why we use prop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly like that, but you could do this:

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.className = "radio";
if( this._getValue(lbl)) btn.className += " checked";
if( this.getDisableProp(lbl)) btn.disabled = true;
```

Sometimes plain JavaScript in multiple steps is easier than trying to chain everything in one go ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your style,

```
  $("<button>")
        .addClass("radio")
        .addClass(this._getValue(lbl) ? "checked" : "") 
        .prop('disabled',this._getDisableProp(lbl));
```

More flexible approach,

```
$("<button>")
    .addClass("radio")
    .addClass(function () {
        if(this._getValue(lbl)) return 'disabled';
     }) 
    .prop('disabled',function () {
        return this._getDisableProp(lbl) ;
     });
```

Also, why are you using both `attr` and `prop` to add `disabled` property. You should be using `prop` only and `disabled` does not require a value.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ (Attributes vs. Properties).. read that says why i used both attr and prop

Comment: I have read that link a lot times. Its always confusing. Can you clarify ?